# Compiler error 'class_name' is not a type and 'class_name' does not name a type C++

Tags: c++, class, compiler-errors, include-guards

I can't understand why I am getting this errors.
When I make the constructor it shows this errors **'bag' is not a type** or **'bag' does not name a type** and if i delete the constructor, it compiles.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "bag.h"

using namespace std;

#ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H

class player {
        string name;
        bag *bag;
    public:
        player(string, bag *);
};

player::player(string name = "DEFAULT_NAME", bag *bag = NULL)
{
    this->name = name;
    this->bag = bag;
}

#endif /* PLAYER_H */
```

Bag class works fine and compiles, but as soon as I try to make a constructor with bag class I get this errors.

Comment: The guards should be 1st, not 3rd.  The `using namespace std;` should not be anywhere in your code at all.  Cannot reproduce, because this isn't a [mcve].

Comment: You need to decide: is `bag` the name of a *class* or the name of a member variable (and function parameter)? It cannot be both.

Comment: does `bag.h` include this header?

Comment: You should not have `player` constructor body in the header (or if you do, mark it as `inline`)

Comment: Okay I did change the guards and removed using namespace std; (it was by mistake) Also I changed the name but i don't know why I didn't had any problems with other classes like ```item item;```. But thank you it works fine know.

Comment: Make sure that `bag.h` does not include `player.h` not even via a third header or any combination of headers.

Comment: fwiw, `item item;` seems to be fine (i am a bit surprised) but not as member: https://godbolt.org/z/yzwQGG, in any case it is poor naming

Comment: In ```main.cpp``` i have declared ```item item``` and it works fine. Also thanks about the link is usefull